# How does APNS token generated?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

What information is used by APNS to generate device tokens and identify that it's unique to the device and app?
I have gone through apple documentation but it only tells that the token is unique to device and app , but how the token gets generated the process is not diclosed.

Answer (score 0):

It's an opaque token. By design, you're not going to be able to reverse engineer how APNS tokens are generated and make your own.

If it helps, you might think of an APNS token as a hash of a bunch of things, some of which you can't see or control.